# Ruby: Unexpected Results from class_exec When Defining Class Variable

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, when defining the contents of a class with `class_exec`, I am getting unexpected results. When I define a class variable in the block sent to `class_exec`, the class variable is being defined on `Object` instead of the class on which `class_exec` is being called:

```
class X; end
X.class_exec do
  @@inner_value = "123"
  def inner_value
    @@inner_value
  end
  def inner_value=(arg)
    @@inner_value = arg
  end
end

obj1 = X.new
puts obj1.inner_value
puts @@inner_value
puts Object.class_variables
```

Produces:

```
123
123
@@inner_value
```

This does not happen when using `class_eval`:

```
X.class_eval(<<-RUBY)
  @@inner_value = "123"
  def inner_value
    @@inner_value
  end
  def inner_value=(arg)
    @@inner_value = arg
  end
RUBY

obj1 = X.new
puts obj1.inner_value
puts @@inner_value
puts Object.class_variables
```

Produces:

```
123
```

and an error:

```
uninitialized class variable @@inner_value in Object (NameError)
```

The results with class_eval are what I would expect to happen in both cases. I have tried this with both MRI 1.8.7 and MRI 1.9.3 and got the same results running on Windows XP.

Is this expected behavior? If so, why? If not, bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class variables are bound to the class in which they are declared *at compile time*.  The block passed to `class_exec` is compiled before it is passed to `class_exec`, so the class variables are bound to `Object`.

I guess your class_exec is at the top level, which is in Object, so that's where they go.  To demonstrate:

```
public

class Object
    @@x = "ribbit"
end

def foo
    puts "test: #{@@x}"
end

x = Object.new
x.foo
```

This is why when you use class vars in a module, all classes that include that module (through the included methods) will see the same class variables.  The class variables are bound to the module.  If you run this:

```
class WithClassVars
    def self.classvars
        @classvars ||= {}
    end

    def classvars
        self.class.classvars
    end
end

class A < WithClassVars;end
class B < WithClassVars;end

a = A.new
b = B.new
a.classvars[:a] = 1
b.classvars[:a] = 2

puts a.classvars
puts b.classvars
```

a and b will end up with the same data.

If you pass your code as a string to `class_eval`, the string is compiled *in* `class_eval`, so you can make sure they are in the right class then.

So if you want to store per-class data, you have to either go with class_eval, or use some mechanism to use a class's instance variables.  Say:

```
class WithClassVars
    def self.classvars
        @classvars ||= {}
    end

    def classvars
        self.class.classvars
    end
end

class A < WithClassVars;end
class B < WithClassVars;end

a = A.new
b = B.new
a.classvars[:a] = 1
b.classvars[:a] = 2

puts a.classvars
puts b.classvars
```