# Dynamically defined classes incorrectly sharing data - bug, or coding error?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I've been trying to set up a system whereby I can generate a series of similar Ruby classes, distinguished by an integer parameter, which I save into a class variable of the relevant class - something akin to C++ templates.

However, referencing (hence, creating) a new version of the templated class overwrites the saved parameters in the previous versions, and I can't work out why.

Here's a minimal example

```
class Object
  def self.const_missing(name)
    if name =~ /^Templ(\d+)$/
      return make_templ $1.to_i
    else
      raise NameError.new("uninitialised constant #{name}")
    end
  end

private
  def make_templ(base)
    # Make sure we don't define twice
    if Object.const_defined? "Templ#{base}"
      return Object.const_get "Templ#{base}"
    else
      # Define a stub class
      Object.class_eval "class Templ#{base}; end"

      # Open the class and define the actual things we need.
      Object.const_get("Templ#{base}").class_exec(base) do |in_base|        
        @@base = in_base

        def initialize
          puts "Inited with base == #{@@base}"
        end
      end

      Object.const_get("Templ#{base}")
    end
  end
end

irb(main):002:0> Templ1.new
Inited with base == 1
=> #<Templ1:0x26c11c8>
irb(main):003:0> Templ2.new
Inited with base == 2
=> #<Templ2:0x20a8370>
irb(main):004:0> Templ1.new
Inited with base == 2
=> #<Templ1:0x261d908>
```

Have I found a bug in my Ruby (ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]), or have I simply coded something wrong?

Comment: Well I spent 45 minutes trying to figure this out, and I guessed something was wrong with variable bindings because you're running a block inside the `Object` class. However I can't take credit for the answer because I finally found the explanation as suspected here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109925/ruby-unexpected-results-from-class-exec-when-defining-class-variable . Your solution is to convert that block into a string and eval it instead so it will be compiled in the right context.

Comment: @Casper when the answer is "use string eval instead of block eval", it's usually time to search for a better answer.  String eval is dangerous and fragile, sometimes it's what you need, but I estimate over 95% of the time I see it used there's a less dangerous form available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you first syntactically reference `@@base` in the context of class Object, it's a class variable of Object and all the TemplX subclasses of object refer to the superclass's class var.  You can change your code to use [Module#class_variable_set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_set) and `class_variable_get` to avoid the binding in the superclass.

A few other issues with your code: I note you didn't make `make_templ` a class method peer of `self.const_missing`, though it dispatched successfully because Object is an ancestor of Class. It's best to avoid all forms of eval(string) when other methods exist. You shouldn't raise NameError if you don't handle the const_missing, but rather dispatch to super as someone else may be in the chain and want to do something to resolve the constant.

```
class Object
  def self.const_missing(name)
    if name =~ /^Templ(\d+)$/
      return make_templ $1.to_i
    end
    super
  end

private
  def self.make_templ(base)
    klass_name = "Templ#{base}"
    unless const_defined? klass_name
      klass = Class.new(Object) do
        class_variable_set :@@base, base
        def initialize
          puts "Inited with base == #{self.class.class_variable_get(:@@base)}"
        end
      end
      const_set klass_name, klass    
    end

    const_get klass_name
  end
end
```

Class variables have interesting and often undesirable information mixing properties through inheritance.  You've hit one of the gotchas.  I don't know what other properties you need around `@@base`, but it looks likely that you'll get better isolation and less suprising results using a class instance variable instead. For more explanation: [Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ClassInstanceVariable.html), [RailsTips](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/)

Comment: If I could +1 you more than once I would! I'll be using class instance variables, I think, but your other tips are golden too. I had thought `super` in `const_missing` would work, as `Object` doesn't define `const_missing`; and I _could not_ figure out how to create the dynamic class name without `eval`, so that's really cool. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @Casper helps point out why your code isn't working. For a fix, consider using class instance variables instead of class variables. This should help you avoid having to `eval` and dodge the common pitfalls of using class variables:

---

**EDIT:** added refactoring from @dbenhur, switching class variable to class instance variable.

```
class Object
  def self.const_missing(name)
    name =~ /^Templ(\d+)$/ ? make_templ($1.to_i) : super
  end

private
  def self.make_templ(base)
    klass_name = "Templ#{base}"
    if const_defined? klass_name
      const_get klass_name
    else
      klass = Class.new(Object) do
        class << self
          attr_accessor :base
        end
        self.base = base
        def initialize
          puts "Inited with base == #{self.class.base}"
        end
      end
      const_set klass_name, klass    
    end
  end
end

puts Templ1.new.class.base
# => Inited with base == 1
# => 1
puts Templ2.new.class.base
# => Inited with base == 2
# => 2
puts Templ1.new.class.base
# => Inited with base == 1
# => 1
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting class instance vars, -1 for not addressing the other issues with OPs code (unnecessary string eval, no super on the else path of const_missing)